# How to migrate Ubuntu VM from Digital Ocean to Azure

Tags: azure, migration, digital-ocean, azure-virtual-machine

Currently I am using Digital Ocean server where the data is hosted. The data is stored in the form of folders inside the Digital ocean server. The python codes are responsible for pushing the data to these folders. There’s no database in the Linux VM. Currently we use username and password using static IP to access the VM. DO’s VM IP is not associated with domain name.

Do you think the migration in this case is easy? Could you share your thoughts as to how I should I go about this? Would be happy to give more information on the same. We are planning to migrate to Azure VM to manage centrally. I would like to know how easy it is to migrate and what are the implications and considerations that I should keep in mind. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the specs of DO Linux VM:

**64 GB Memory / 1 TB Disk / SGP1 - Ubuntu CTS**

Comment: Create a VM in Azure and FTP the files?

Comment: What do you mean by FTP the files?